# C# Razor - How do you remove double quotes from string

Tags: c#, razor, stringbuilder, razor-pages

This is the exact html out-put that I want in the browser:

```
<button class="snipcart-add-item"
        data-item-id="starry-night"
        data-item-price="8.00"
        data-item-url="menu/rice-meals/"
        data-item-description="Best Rice in town"
        data-item-image="/media/v01dq2ye/rice-small.jpg"
        data-item-name="Jollof Rice"

        data-item-custom1-name="Stew"
        data-item-custom1-options="Aye-Mase|Red"

        data-item-custom2-name="Side"
        data-item-custom2-options="Beans|Plantain|Plantain & Beans[+0.50]"

        data-item-custom3-name="Meat"
        data-item-custom3-options="Fuku|Beef|Cow foot[+1.00]"

        data-item-custom4-name="rice"
        data-item-custom4-options="White|Jollof Rice| Fried Rice[+1.00]">

    Add to cart
</button>
```

This is my Razor:

```
    <button class="snipcart-add-item"
        data-item-id="@product.ProductId"
        data-item-price="@product.Price"
        data-item-url="@product.ProductUrl"
        data-item-description="Need to put a description here"
        data-item-image="@product.ProductImageUrl"
        data-item-name="@product.ProductName"

        @{
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            int currentCount = 1;
        }

        @foreach (var option in product.ProductOptions)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format("data-item-custom{0}-name='{1}'", currentCount,option.OptionName));

            sb.Append(string.Format("data-item-custom{0}-options='{1}'", currentCount, option.OptionsAsSnipCartString));

            currentCount++;
        }

        @sb.ToString()
        >

    Add to cart
</button>
```

and this is the out put I am getting, almost its not quite right I have an extra quotes.

```
data-item-custom1-name="'Stew'
data-item-custom1-options='Aya-Mase|Red-Stew'
data-item-custom2-name='Rice'
data-item-custom2-options='Jollof-Rice|White-Rice|Fried-Rice'
data-item-custom3-name='Side'
data-item-custom3-options='Plaintain|Beans|Plaintain-And-Beans[+0.50]'
data-item-custom4-name='Meat'data-item-custom4-options='Beef|Shaki|Fuku|Abodi'">

    Add to cart
</button>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

1. I have got "" around the "whole thing", I need to remove that from the output.
2. I'm using single quotes 'value' for the values, but I should be using double "value" 
   To match the example output.

Comment: how about if you use just ``"data-item-custom{0}-name={1}"``

Comment: @Sajid what do you mean?

Comment: if i understand correctly the issue i mean that ``sb.Append(string.Format("data-item-custom{0}-name={1}", currentCount,option.OptionName));`` without single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work..

I just changed

```
@sb.ToString()
```

to

```
@(new HtmlString(sb.ToString()))
```